# How to append elements to a pair of coordinates to make a multidimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list containing the pair of coordinates as following:

```
index = [(1, 4), (3, 6), (7, 10), (3, 9)]
```

now I have list with same size as following:

```
size = [2, 2, 4, 4]
```

Now I would like to append the "size" to "index" in order to look like the following:

```
new = [(1,4,2), (3,6,2), (7,10,4), (3,9,4)]
```

I have tried a bunch of stuff such as "zip" or "numpy.dstack((index, size)).shape"

but does not give me desired format.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
[i+(j,) for i,j in zip(index,size)]
# [(1, 4, 2), (3, 6, 2), (7, 10, 4), (3, 9, 4)]
```

Timeit analysis:

```
# When list size is 4
In [142]: timeit [(*i,j) for i,j in zip(index, size)] #yatu's answer
1.24 µs ± 72.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [144]: timeit [i+(j,) for i,j in zip(index,size)] #Ch3steR's answer
902 ns ± 28.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

When list of tuples size over 10,000.

```
In [149]: timeit [(*i,j) for i,j in zip(index, size)]
1.68 ms ± 77.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [150]: timeit [i+(j,) for i,j in zip(index,size)]
1.18 ms ± 27.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Little faster than unpacking approach

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip` to aggregate both iterables, then create a new tuple by unpacking the tuples in `index` and adding the integers in `size` to it:

```
[(*i,j) for i,j in zip(index, size)]
# [(1, 4, 2), (3, 6, 2), (7, 10, 4), (3, 9, 4)]
```

Comment: This is what I get [((1, 4), 2), ((2, 8), 2)], I am using Python 2.7,

Comment: If unpacking does not work because of your version, use `[i + (j,) for i,j in zip(index, size)]` @ash